# If $a^2 + b^2 +c^2 = 3$ then prove $1/(ab+1) + 1/(bc+1) + 1/(ca+1) \geq 3/2$

Tags: inequality

First, I tried to used power mean inequality on $1/ab , 1/bc , 1/ca$ but that wasn't useful here. Then I used Am-HM on $1/ab+1 , 1/bc+1 , 1/ca+1$ but couldn't. So I figured out how to use $a^2 + b^2 +c^2 = 3$ with AM-GM but couldn't too.

** What would be an efficient method to solve this problem? Please provide only a hint and not the entire solution since I wish to solve it myself.

Comment: Perhaps trig function as we have : $$\cot(a)\cot(b)+\cot(b)\cot(c)+\cot(c)\cot(a)=1,a+b+c=\pi$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$ab+bc+ca\leq a^2+b^2+c^2$$ we have $$(ab+1)+(bc+1)+(ca+1)\leq 6$$ Now use Am-Hm inequality for $ab+1$, $bc+1$ and $ca+1$.

Comment: thank youuuu >: